# jquery 1.10 $.ajax with $.each call to finish (phonegap)

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, each

I am having a problem with my ajax calls in jquery and keeping the screen showing a loading icon until 100% finished processing.

I am using this with phonegap and the database, so that items pulled from ajax are loaded into the database.  The code runs fine and the database is 100% populated,  but my "#block-ui" is disapparing before the database $.each calls 100% complete.  Also my #sync text shows in random order.

Since I am using jquery 1.10, I know async: false no longer works.  Can someone help.

```
function SyncIt() {
    $('#recap').text('');
    $('#syncit').attr("href", "#");
    var db = window.openDatabase("titanware", "1.0", "TitanRoof", 50000000);
    $('#block-ui').show();
    $('#sync').text('Syncing with Titanware');
    db.transaction(function(tx) {tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM active_jobs WHERE jb_active != 1');},dbErrorHandler);
    db.transaction(function(tx) {tx.executeSql('DELETE FROM employees');},dbErrorHandler);

// Sync Jobs    
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://xxxxxxxxx/api/api.php?request_type=m_clients',
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
    $('#sync').text('Syncing Jobs');
    }
    }).done(function(data) {

    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
    // Load Data into the database for jobs        
    db.transaction(function(tx) {tx.executeSql("insert into active_jobs(job_no, comp_name, comp_street, comp_suite, comp_city, comp_state, comp_zip, comp_contact, comp_phone, comp_cell, comp_notes, jb_active) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", [item.job_no,item.comp_name,item.comp_street,item.comp_suite,item.comp_city,item.comp_state,item.comp_zip,item.comp_contact,item.comp_phone,item.comp_cell,item.comp_notes,'0']);},dbErrorHandler);

    })

    db.transaction(function(tx){
    tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM active_jobs', [], function(tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length;
    // Show total jobs synced in the #recap div
    $('#recap').text('Jobs Synced: ' + len);
    });
    });

    });

// Sync Employees   
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://xxxxxxx/api/api.php?request_type=get_employees',
    crossDomain: true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
    $('#sync').text('Syncing Employees');
    }
    }).done(function(data) { 
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
    //Load employees in the database  
    db.transaction(function(tx) {tx.executeSql("insert into employees(user_id, full_name) values(?,?)", [item.user_id,item.full_name]);},dbErrorHandler);

    })

    $('#sync').text('Almost Done'); 
    $('#block-ui').hide();

    });

}
```

Thanks for any feedback

Answer (score 0):

Add `async:false` in your `$.ajax` call.

By default it is true, so the requests are sent asynchronously.

Refer [jQuery.ajax() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) for more details.

Hope that helps.

Comment: The async:false flag no longer works in Jquery 1.10.  It was depreciated in 1.8.  I had it in the code,  but then found out that 1.8 depreciated the code. Looking for ideas to make the code work while using the latest jquery build.

Comment: Then you will have to apply your own logic like setting some flag. As the documentation says use `jqXHR.done()`

Comment: That is where I am getting lost.  Everything I try, breaks the ajax call or the database loop.  Still learning jquery, so guess I will keep trying.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out by moving the hide #block-ui to the end of the insert loop of jobs. This keeps the sync icon on the screen until that part of the ajax loop has finished.

Comment: Good you figured it out. :) Better edit your answer and post the working code. It may help someone someday.